# Pybrain implementation throwing error

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, pybrain

I am trying to generate a grid for my dataset of 10 dimensions, while doing so I am following the code from http://pybrain.org/docs/tutorial/fnn.html. The code which I am implementing and throwing error is:

```
 ticks = arange(-3.,6.,0.2)
 X, Y = meshgrid(ticks, ticks)
 # need column vectors in dataset, not arrays
 griddata = ClassificationDataSet(10,1, nb_classes=3)
 for i in xrange(X.size):
      griddata.addSample([X.ravel()[i],Y.ravel()[i]], [0])
```

The error that I am getting is:

```
 File "a.py", line 224, in <module>
  griddata.addSample([X.ravel()[i], Y.ravel()[i]], [0])
 File "a.py", line 45, in addSample
  self.appendLinked(inp, target)
 File "a.py", line 216, in appendLinked
  self._appendUnlinked(l, args[i])
 File "a.py", line 198, in _appendUnlinked
  self.data[label][self.endmarker[label], :] = row
 ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 2 to array axis with dimension 7
```

I am not getting how to correct the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is already given by Python: dimensions are your problem. You create a dataset with 10 dimensions: 
`ClassificationDataSet(in_dim, out_dim, class_num)`
as the first number is for dimensions. 
And then you try to add a sample with 2 dimensions to that dataset: 
`griddata.addSample([in1, in2, in3..., in_last], [out1])`.
The example you provide here is exactly from the pybrain tutorial, just you wrongly copied that one number, the in_dimensions. It was 2 in the example. And then it should work.

Comment: I was having the same issue following this tutorial, and I resolved it but now when I try to call `activateOnDataset` I get AssertionError (8,2) since my dataset takes in 8 inputs, and griddata takes in two. How can I make a sqaure grid with 8 inputs?

Comment: What do you mean @mattgabor dataset takes 8 inputs and griddata takes 2 ??
Whatever you are calling, your training dataset as well as your testing dataset have to have same dimensions.

Comment: Okay that makes sense, so I need griddata to be of dimensions `ClassificationDataSet(10,1, nb_classes=3)`, so I must add 10 samples instead of two like you mentioned above. But if I want to use `X.ravel()[i]` and `Y.ravel()[i]` like they do in the pybrain tutorial how can I do ravel for 10 inputs?

Comment: @mattgabor Dataset size (or number samples) and dimensions aren't the same.
Dataset (10,1, nb_classes=3), 10 stands for input array shape or length indeed, and 1 stands for target array shape. The number or samples is of your choice. 
Check tutorials on DataSets http://pybrain.org/docs/quickstart/dataset.html and http://pybrain.org/docs/api/datasets/classificationdataset.html